# Using linearize method in app designer standalone app

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm using the linearize method to linearize a simulink model in in my matlab script. It works when i run it in the app designer.

But after creating a standalone desktop app it doesnt work.

I want to get the transfer function from my simulink model. The model is too complex to create it in the script.

```
linsys = linearize('simulinkSys',io); %get state space model from simulink

A=linsys.A; B=linsys.B; C=linsys.C; D=linsys.D;
[GmassSystemNum,GmassSystemDen] = ss2tf(A,B,C,D); %convert to transfer function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation [Functions not supported by MATLAB Compiler / MATLAB Compiler SDK](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/unsupported-functions.html) , Simulink functionality is not support when creating standalone applications.